# Kafka Streams not writing to sink topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to learn Kafka Streams using Confluent's test platform and [the setup instruction here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html). I can start up and connect to my test broker, but the streams application never writes to my sink topic. Looking in the logs, Kafka Streams is constantly fetching and monitoring the offset (if I am reading the logs correctly), but it never actually reads or writes anything.

```
14:07:29.654 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Received successful Heartbeat response
14:07:29.770 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 4 for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=4, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
14:07:29.770 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 at offset 4 to node localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:29.770 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0] to broker localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:30.273 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 4 for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=4, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
14:07:30.273 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 at offset 4 to node localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:30.273 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0] to broker localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:30.775 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 4 for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=4, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
14:07:30.776 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 at offset 4 to node localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:30.776 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0] to broker localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:31.279 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 4 for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=4, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
14:07:31.279 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 at offset 4 to node localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:31.279 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0] to broker localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:31.782 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 4 for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=4, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
14:07:31.782 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 at offset 4 to node localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:31.782 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0] to broker localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:32.284 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 4 for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=4, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
14:07:32.284 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0 at offset 4 to node localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:32.284 [katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [exportStatusUpdatesV2_rquinlivan-0] to broker localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)
14:07:32.656 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | katanaTest] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=katanaTest-a821659c-a994-4c6f-9714-fa48020b6378-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=katanaTest] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator localhost:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
```

I don't understand from this stack trace what the issue is, and there is never an error logged. How can I debug why my streams application isn't working? What is the recommended method of debugging in Kafka Streams?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of your Kafka stream code?

Comment: Do you write new data to the topic while the application is running? Did you disable Kafka Streams record cache by setting cache size to zero?